# C# Fire event from outlook

Tags: email, outlook, c#-3.0

Is possible to fire an event in c# when ever user responds to an email using outlook?

I have an approval system which sends out an email to customers, so I am thinking instead of asking customers to login to a portal simply they can respond to email 
and I can catch and store that in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, on the receiving side, use Application.NewMailEx event to open the customer's reply.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I did not follow you. Is there a sample or blog which gives me more details.